# Sum from infinity to infinity of infinity

Tags: summation, infinity

What is $\sum_{n=∞}^{∞}∞$? Indeterminate? Is the answer the same for $\sum_{n=∞}^{∞}k$ for any non-zero $k$?

This is probably a dumb and also useless question but I was just curious. Thanks!

Comment: Have you learned about series? Or you just know the summation notation?

Comment: @ĐàoMinhDũng I have learned about series.

Comment: Formally, $\infty$ should not appear as either limit or as the summand.  When we say $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ what we *really* mean is $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_n$.  In your case you have $\infty$ appearing both as bottom limit, top limit, *and* summand.  You should rewrite this expression with limits so it is unambiguous whether all of these "infities" are "the same" or not.

Comment: Consider for instance $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{2N} 1$ which is equal to $N$ for each value of $N$ and so the sum diverges to infinity and compare that to $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=N}^{N+1} 1$ which is equal to $1$ for each value of $N$.  In both cases, you have the upper and lower limits of the summation are both unbounded, and so might have to a lay person both been equally valid as $\sum\limits_{n=\infty}^\infty 1$ despite giving different results.  The point is the upper limit in the first grew much faster than in the second.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks so much! This was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we require the summation variable to be an integer.  $\infty$ is not an integer.  We allow things like $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty$ as a shorthand for $\lim_{m \to -\infty} \lim_{n=\infty} \sum_{i=m}^n$ because it is useful.  $\sum_{n=\infty}^\infty$ does not have a meaning that I recognize.  If you define it clearly, the question will have an answer.